# Carrierwave russian file names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, utf-8, character-encoding, carrierwave

I need save files with russian name or transliterate file name. I try this:

1) In document_uploader:

```
def filename
  @name ||= "#{Russian::transliterate(original_filename)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end
```

2) In document.rb:

I create before_create callback method with the same logic but not see any results.

Name of file after uploading like this: "______________.doc"

What I should do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using ruby 1.9, you can sanitize the file name, it's likley because the characters are not unicode:

```
CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Rails 4.2.11.3 `empty range in char class: /[^[:word:].-+]/` when I try to load the application